# Fundamental group of the moduli space of parabolic bundles with fixed determinant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, fano-varieties

I am looking for the **fundamental group of the moduli space of parabolic bundles with fixed determinant over a smooth projective curve**.

I know that the fundamental group of the moduli space of vector bundles with fixed determinant is trivial as it is Fano (Unirationality and Picard number one implies Fano). But I am not sure whether the same is true for the parabolic case.

Also, I wonder if the higher homotopy groups of the moduli space of parabolic bundles are known. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: The moduli space is still rational (not just unirational), hence simply connected (in fact, all separably rationally connected, smooth projective varieties over an algebraically closed field are simply connected -- char 0 by Campana, char p by Koll'ar and Debarre).  In characteristic 0, by Hurewicz, the map from $\pi_2$ to $H_2$ is an isomorphism, and these are free Abelian groups of rank $1$ (if no parabolic structure).  For $\pi_3$, already the Jacobian of the curve intercedes.  I believe this is worked out in the textbook of Griffiths-Morgan.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So since the moduli space of parabolic bundles is rational, it is simply connected. Is the isomorphism from $\pi_2$ to $H_2$ true for the parabolic case (in characteristic zero)?

Comment: That follows from the Hurewicz Isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.